# Re-raise and re-catch error immediately in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have some exception handling code in `python` where two exceptions can be raised, the first one being a "superset" of the second one.

I.e. the following code summarizes what I need to do (and works fine)

```
try:
    normal_execution_path()
except FirstError:
    handle_first_error()
    handle_second_error()
except SecondError:
    handle_second_error()
```

But it requires me to abstract everything into independent functions for the code to remain clean and readable. I was hopping for some simpler syntax like:

```
try:
    normal_execution_path()
except FirstError:
    handle_first_error()
    raise SecondError
except SecondError:
    handle_second_error()
```

But this does not seem to work (`SecondError` does not get re-catched if it is raised inside this block). Is there anything doable in that direction though ?

Comment: You can't unless you specify an additional handler. Branching on if the error is an instance of `FirstError` or `SecondError` seems better here.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to manually throw the second error to be handled, you can use nested try-catch blocks like these:

```
try:
    normal_execution_path()
except FirstError:
    try:
        handle_first_error()
        raise SecondError
    except SecondError:
        handle_second_error()
except SecondError:
        handle_second_error()
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps it is worth reviewing the code architecture. But for your particular case:

Create a generic class that handles this type of error. To inherit from it for the first and second error cases. Create a handler for this type of error. In the handler, check the first or second special case and process it with a waterfall.

```
class SupersetException(Exception):
    pass


class FirstError(SupersetException):
    pass


class SecondError(SupersetException):
    pass


def normal_execution_path():
    raise SecondError


def handle_superset_ex(state):
    # Our waterfall
    # We determine from whom the moment to start processing the exception.
    if type(state) is FirstError:
        handle_first_error()
    # If not the first, the handler above will be skipped 
    handle_second_error()


try:
    normal_execution_path()
except SupersetException as state:
    handle_superset_ex(state)
```

Then just develop the idea.